# Ribbon Button showing wrong LabelText

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon

I have a Ribbon Button with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.AddAButton"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
  RegistrationId="171"
    RegistrationType="List"
    Title="Change Email Ribbon Button">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit.NewRibbonButton"
          Command="ChangeEmailButtonCommand"
          Image16by16="/_layouts/15/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png?rev=23" Image16by16Top="-127" Image16by16Left="-91"
          Image32by32="/_layouts/15/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23" Image32by32Top="-477" Image32by32Left="-307"
          LabelText="$Resources:Toolkit,ChangeEmailButtonLabel"
          TemplateAlias="o2" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="ChangeEmailButtonCommand"
          CommandAction="javascript:
            ChangeEmailAction();
          " />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
  <CustomAction Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit.Scripts" Location="ScriptLink" ScriptSrc="/_layouts/15/GOToolkit/JS/loadJsOrCssFile.js?version=1.7.3" />
</Elements>
```

Now, the `LabelText` on my button, shows the exact same text, as it does in the XML: `"$Resources:Toolkit,ChangeemailButtonLabel"`, where I'd expect it to show the text that I have defined in the `'ChangeEmailButtonLabel`', which looks like this:

```
  <data name="ChangeEmailButtonLabel" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Change email</value>
  </data>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Where is the resources files deployed?

Comment: They're deployed at {SharePointRoot}\Resources